# react-router-dom: history does not reload (render) page automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-dom

i'm using redux, redux-saga, among other dependencies, i'm trying to redirect the page after logging in, using history.push(), but it doesn't work. So, to work around the problem, I'm using window.location.reload () right after that.

Here part of my code:

```html
export function* signIn({ payload }) {
  try {
    const { email, password } = payload;
  
    const response = yield call(api.post, 'sessions', {
      email,
      password
    });

    const { token, user } = response.data;

    yield put(signInSuccess(token, user));

    history.push('/home');
    window.location.reload();
  } catch(err) {
    yield put(signFailure());
  }
}
```

And my App.js:

```html
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <Routes />
          <ToastContainer autoClose={4000}/>
        </Router>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Why it happens? I read that it is because in the recent versions of the router / history, the history is not working as it used to, it does not automatically redirect, I don't know, I think that's what I understood.

**Does anybody know how to solve this? Without having to use window.location.reload() every time?**

Sorry for my english, I'm from brazil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youre not using React Router `history` in your `signIn` saga, so it wont redirect using the router. Since the saga cant do that, youll have to move that into the component that calls the `signIn` instead.

I usually add a callback to the `signIn`, that inside the component that calls the `signIn`, can redirect with `history` after a successful call.